# Hp printer works but scanner does not after installing 16.04

Tags: hp, 16.04, scanner, ubuntu-gnome, hplip

In Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 `hplip` software does not find all-in-one printer (127fn). GNOME can find the printer and it works fine, but the scanner does not work with usb and network.

The output of `hplip-setup` command:

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.16.3)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Searching... (bus=net, timeout=5, ttl=4, search=(None) desc=0, method=slp)
error: No devices found on bus: net
warning:  HPLIP cannot detect printers in your network.  This may be due to existing firewall settings blocking the required ports.
                When you are in a trusted network environment, you may open the ports for network services like mdns and slp in the firewall. For detailed steps follow the link.
                 http://hplipopensource.com/node/375
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "automatic" (recommended) install does not include sane support.  To fix, just remove and purge the install done as "automatic" and reinstall answering (c)ustom at about the 3rd choice you have to make.  A couple of questions later you'll have to go through five or so choices for support.  Be sure to choose the "Network/JetPrint" option as well as the "sane" support option.

The only big difference between the automatic and custom installs is that the automatic install does 3 of the 5 choices and you get a "spinner" to show progress through the "make" and "make install" steps rather than looking at the information stream that flows by as the step is running.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo hp-setup -i
```

The `-i` key is essential, because without it the setup doesn't proceed. At this time I still haven't gotten the test page out, but the scanner is working properly, which is what I needed originally.